# Compiler optimization of a switch statement for state machines

Tags: c, gcc, x86, clang, compiler-optimization

The following code example defines a kind of typical state machine.  A `switch` statement handles each state per `case` label, and the state machine is exited once a particular state is reached:

```
int f1 (int i);
int f2 (int i);
int f3 (int i);
int f4 (int i);
int f5 (int i);
int f6 (int i);
int f7 (int i);

extern int b;

void
m (int x)
{
  do
    {
      switch (x)
        {
        case 11:
          x = f1 (10);
          break;
        case 1:
          x = f2 (12);
          break;
        case 2:
          x = f3 (13);
          break;
        case 4:
          x = f4 (999);
          break;
        case 5:
          x = f5 (0);
          break;
        case 7:
          x = f6 (11);
          break;
        case 10:
          x = f7 (1000);
          break;
        default:
          __builtin_unreachable ();
        }
    }
  while (__builtin_expect (x != b, 1));
}
```

Compiling the code with the trunk version of GCC 12 (using the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org)) and with `-O3` gives the following assembly:

```
m:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    %edi, %eax
.L12:
        movl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     *.L4(,%rax,8)
.L4:
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L10
        .quad   .L9
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L8
        .quad   .L7
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L6
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L3
        .quad   .L5
        .quad   .L3
.L5:
        movl    $1000, %edi
        call    f7
.L11:
        cmpl    %eax, b(%rip)
        jne     .L12
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L6:
        movl    $11, %edi
        call    f6
        jmp     .L11
.L7:
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        call    f5
        jmp     .L11
.L8:
        movl    $999, %edi
        call    f4
        jmp     .L11
.L9:
        movl    $13, %edi
        call    f3
        jmp     .L11
.L10:
        movl    $12, %edi
        call    f2
        jmp     .L11
.L3:
        movl    $10, %edi
        call    f1
        jmp     .L11
```

As one can clearly see, at the end of each `case` block, the CPU has to go to three jumps.  The first jump goes to `.L11`, where the termination condition is checked, the second jump goes to `.L12`, where the new state is dispatched and the final jump is through the jump table at `.L4` to the code of the new state.

This looks quite inefficient to me.  Usually, the transition probabilities from one state to the next one are far from uniformly distributed, so the CPU branch predictor could help a lot.  But isn't the branch predictor neutralized when everything is threaded through the single indirect branch just before `.L4`?

Why doesn't GCC inline some code at the end of each `case` block?  It looks much more efficient to me if every `case` block ended with:

```
        cmpl    %eax, b(%rip)
        je      .Lxx
        movl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     *.L4(,%rax,8)
```

For a small increase of code size, we would be down to one taken branch instead of three, and the indirect branch is isolated per case.

How can I tell GCC to generate such code? Or am I mistaken and the code GCC generates is actually good? For what it's worth, Clang generates similar code as GCC according to my experiments.

Comment: *But isn't the branch predictor neutralized when everything is threaded through the single indirect branch just before .L4?* - fortunately no, Intel since Haswell uses IT-TAGE which can predict complex patterns for a single indirect branch. Also AMD since Zen2, with Zen1 using Perceptron.  See [Branch Prediction and the Performance of Interpreters -
Don’t Trust Folklore](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01100647/document).  Your suggestion might still be a useful optimization, though; I'll have a look at it later.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for that very helpful reference. I've learned something new.